# Trying to pull additional values from XML-bound comboBox that are not DisplayMemberPath, etc

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

I have a comboBox bound to an XML file. The user selects a site from this comboBox which, in turn, is then bound to another comboBox so that they can select a subnet at this site.

This works fine. However, now I need to pull additional info from that subnet node in then xml file and am completely lost. I'm in gyro scope mode (spinning around frantically, not actually getting anywhere). I'm still very new to WPF and this is my first attempt at any kind of data binding. (Also, this isn't my "day job" - I'm on the Systems side but enjoy scripting or coding anything that saves me time.)

Here's what I have so far:

The xml file:

```
<Sites>
  <Site>
    <SiteCode>WDH</SiteCode>
    <Name>World Domination Headquarters, Inc.</Name>
    <Subnet>
      <NetworkAddress>10.10.1.0</NetworkAddress>
      <VlanID>1</VlanID>
      <VlanName>Default</VlanName>
      <DHCPSrv>10.10.1.99</DHCPSrv>
      <DHCPSrvType>W2k8</DHCPSrvType>
    </Subnet>
    <Subnet>
      <NetworkAddress>10.10.2.0</NetworkAddress>
      <VlanID>2</VlanID>
      <VlanName>Mgmt</VlanName>
      <DHCPSrv>10.10.2.1</DHCPSrv>
      <DHCPSrvType>C2951</DHCPSrvType>
    </Subnet>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

XML binding in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider 
            x:Name="xmlSites"
            XPath="Sites/Site"
            Source="SiteInfo.xml" />
</Grid.DataContext>
```

The combobox that selects the site:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SiteNameCboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedIndex="-1"
</ComboBox>
```

The bound combobox then used to select one of that site's subnets:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DHCPServerCboBox"
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SiteNameCboBox}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Subnet}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                        <Binding XPath="NetworkAddress"/>
                        <Binding XPath="VlanName"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>                          
</ComboBox>
```

So far, so good. Everything works. But....now in the code behind, I need to get the values for 
NetworkAddress, DHCPSrv and DHCPSrvType from the SelectedItem.

In addition to the many embarrassing things that didn't work (I'm like a monkey with power tools), I
tried variations on:

```
Dim DHCPSrv As String
Dim cboItem As ComboBoxItem = TryCast(DHCPServerCboBox.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem)
DHCPSrv = Convert.ToString(cboItem.DHCPSvr)
```

And I get "DHCPSrv not a member of 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'. Which, if I'm translating
that correctly, means "Guess again..."

I've been trying to figure out if SelectedItem is the thread I should be pulling on, but I may
be completely off base. Any help anyone can offer will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnswer001.Window3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider 
            x:Name="xmlSites"
            XPath="Sites/Site"
            Source="SiteInfo.xml" />
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <ComboBox x:Name="SiteNameCboBox"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectionChanged="SiteNameCboBox_SelectionChanged"
              SelectedIndex="-1">
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

You can use Xpath directly in C# as follows:

```
    private void SiteNameCboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = SiteNameCboBox.SelectedItem as XmlElement;
        var networkAddress = selectedItem.SelectSingleNode("Subnet/NetworkAddress").InnerText;
        var dhscpServer = selectedItem.SelectSingleNode("Subnet/DHCPSrv").InnerText;
        var dhcpServerType = selectedItem.SelectSingleNode("Subnet/DHCPSrvType").InnerText;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together such a detailed answer! I think this gets me headed in the right direction. I'd like to bind them (eg dhcpServer) directly to the var and skip the textbox (I'm using these in the code, not presenting in the UI). So, I should be looking at how to bind the variables in code / outside XAML...? (I'm doing some digging now to see what I can come up with.)

Comment: I have updated the answer, I hope it fits your needs now. Cheers!

Comment: That worked! Absolutely perfect! Thank you very much!